# Calculate number of days in a Time range?

Tags: ruby

I have the following range:

```
range = Time.now-1.month..Time.now
```

How can I calculate the number of days in that range?

I'm running Ruby 2.0.0.

Comment: Errr, I guess. Didn't realize those were Rails-specific methods.

Comment: `1.month` is I think rails code

Comment: @ArupRakshit, you do not need Rails, just [active support](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html).

Comment: @Shpigford This might be `Timelord` gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
range = Time.now .. Time.now-1.month
=> 2013-12-13 15:35:57 -0500..2013-11-13 15:35:57 -0500
((range.first - range.last) / 1.day).ceil
=> 30
```

Comment: But wouldn't `1.month.ago` be *at least* 30 days? At least in all months except ones involving February?

Comment: @Spigford, yep, `floor` rounded 29.9999... down to 29. Changed it to `ceil` which rounds up to 30.

Answer (score 0):

The `#<<` method of Date subtracts a month (#>> adds one). Subtracting dates results in days.

```
require 'date'

p (Date.today - (Date.today << 1)).to_i #=> 30
#so:
range = Time.now-1.month..Time.now
p p (range.last.to_date - range.first.to_date).to_i #=>30
```

Answer (score 0):

`1.month` [will always be 30 days](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer/time.rb#L35-L38), so your range will always be a 30-day range. If you want to find out the number of days in this month, since you already have ActiveSupport available, you can just use `Time#days_in_month`:

```
Time.days_in_month(Time.now.month, Time.now.year)
# => 31

Time.days_in_month(Time.now.month - 1, Time.now.year)
# => 30
```

Comment: Reason for the downvote? ActiveSupport literally defines Integer#month as a 30-day duration.